# Python error with super

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance

I am trying to create a Class Person and inherit it to class Student with the following codes. When I try to run

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, idNumber):
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.idNumber = idNumber
    def printPerson(self):
        print "Name:", self.lastName + ",", self.firstName
        print "ID:", self.idNumber
class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, idNumber, scores):
        super(Student, self).__init__(firstName, lastName, idNumber)
        self.scores = scores
    def calculate(self):
        if self.scores > 90:
            print('Honor Student')
```

And I do,

```
s = Student('Sam', 'Smith', 123456, 95)
s.calculate()
```

I was assuming it should print 'Honor Student' however it throws a typeError giving me following message TypeError: must be type, not classobj on super. What am I doing wrong here. I saw few post with similar problems but can't get to work on mine.

Comment: Can you post the actual traceback?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last)
     14         if self.scores > 90:
     15             print('Honor Student')
---> 16 s = Student('Sam', 'Smith', 123456, 95)
     17 s.calculate()
in __init__(self, firstName, lastName, idNumber, scores)
      9 class Student(Person):
     10     def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, idNumber, scores):
---> 11         super(Student, self).__init__(firstName, lastName, idNumber)
     12         self.scores = scores
     13     def calculate(self):

TypeError: must be type, not classobj

Answer (score 2):

The use of [`super`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) only works for [new-type classes](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-new-style-class).

All you need to do is to have `Person` inherit from `object` in the class definition.

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, idNumber):
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.idNumber = idNumber

    def printPerson(self):
        print "Name:", self.lastName + ",", self.firstName
        print "ID:", self.idNumber


class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, idNumber, scores):
        super(Student, self).__init__(firstName, lastName, idNumber)
        self.scores = scores

    def calculate(self):
        if self.scores > 90:
            print('Honor Student')
```

Note that in Python 3 all classes are new-type, so the explicit inheritance from object is not necessary.